# What are good ways to save and manage all versions of programs and their associated data?

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on a research project and what I need to do is to modify the programs (or write new scripts) and generate data. I would like to save all versions of programs and data so that I could easily compare different versions of program-data pairs at the same time.

There are some methods I used previously:

1. manage all the stuff by hand: every time before I modify a program, I copy the unmodified version and the associated data into a folder, and then modify and run new programs. This works, but not convenient, and sometimes I forgot to do this copy-and-paste step and lost some versions.
2. Git: this would be good for version control, but not easy for direct comparison of different versions of programs and data since Git does not save all versions at the same time (e.g. it would be hard to compare version 1,3,7,14 of programs and data).

I am wondering are there any other ways to save and manage all versions of programs and their associated data? By the way, I spend half of my time working on Windows and the other half on Linux.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use git branches. Just create a new branch for each version and continue development on the main branch.

Comment: @nalyd88 That would not be convenient, because I cannot load different branches in my folder at the same time for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question what sort of comparisons you'd be doing between the data produced by the various versions of your program.  However, if I assume that the goal is for the result of your calculations to remain unchanged between versions, then the solution you might be looking for is a combination of (a) version control and (b) unit testing.

Version control using git allows you to commit your code at "known good states."  The way that you know that a state is "good" before committing is by running a series of unit tests that you've written.  If the changes don't cause a any unit tests to fail, then you assume that nothing is broken, and you commit.  If you find a bug in your code, you write a unit test that fails due to that bug, and then write a "patch" that fixes the bug and causes the test to pass.  If the bug ever re-appears, you'll know because the test will begin to fail as a result of the change.

I've used [git](https://github.com/) and [ctest](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/ctest.html) for this purpose on Linux--I know that they can also be used on Windows, though I don't personally have experience with it.

**However, if you truly do need to save the data as well:**

1. If the amount of data is reasonably small, and if it's text-based, you may be just fine committing it right along with your code.
2. If the amount of data is large, or if it is some sort of binary format, look into git's [large file storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) extension.

Comment: Thanks!  To be short, my goal is to save all data and also know which version of programs generate them.  Suppose I have data_1, data_2, ...., I should have program_1, program_2,...  in the same folder with these data.

Comment: @username123 -- I've added an update to address the issue of actually versioning the data.